Thread in rust for chess engine not running the code inside the thread
I am trying to write a chess engine using rust and I want it to be able to start a thread so that it can listen for uci commands while it is thinking. Here is a simplified version of my code that works as expected, passing the stop flag and handle to the main thread so that the main thread can stop the ai thread and then join it.

    #[test]
    fn start_thread() {
        let test_struct = TestStruct { stop_flag: None, test_data: String::from("not modified") };
        println!("{}", test_struct.test_data);
        let x = test_struct.start_thread();
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        let test_struct = x.stop();
        println!("{}", test_struct.test_data);
    }

    pub struct ThreadInfo {
        stop_flag: Arc<AtomicBool>,
        join_handle: JoinHandle<TestStruct>,
    }

    impl ThreadInfo {
        pub fn stop(self) -> TestStruct {
            println!("stopping");
            self.stop_flag.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
            println!("stop flag main thread: {}", self.stop_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
            let mut ai = self.join_handle.join().expect("failed to join thread");
            ai.stop_flag = None;
            println!("stopped");
            ai
        }
    }

    struct TestStruct {
        stop_flag: Option<Arc<AtomicBool>>,
        test_data: String,
    }

    impl TestStruct {
        pub fn start_thread(mut self) -> ThreadInfo {
            let stop_flag = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
            let stop_flag_clone = Arc::clone(&stop_flag);
            self.stop_flag = Some(stop_flag_clone);

            println!("starting");

            let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                println!("thread start");
                loop {
                    println!("thread running");
                    //let start_time = Instant::now();
                    //let evaluation = self.negamax(&self.game.deep_clone(), depth, 0, -INFINITY, INFINITY);
                    //let pv_string = self.reconstruct_principal_variation();
                    if let Some(stop_flag) = &self.stop_flag {
                        if stop_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed) { break; }
                    }
                    self.test_data = String::from("modified");
                    //let depth_duration = start_time.elapsed();
                    //Self::uci_print_evaluation_info(evaluation, depth, depth_duration, pv_string);
                    //self.uninterupted_best_move = Some(self.last_principal_variation[0]);
                }
                self
            });

            println!("started {:?}", handle);

            ThreadInfo {
                stop_flag: stop_flag,
                join_handle: handle,
            }
        }
    }

The problem is, this is a simplified version of the actual code in my engine, and that doesn't work. I put a panic! statement in the first line of the thread, just to see if it is running the code inside the thread, and it does not panic. When I did that for the simplified code it did panic and produce an error message. The stop flag doesn't actually stop the thread and it never joins. I can't see how my code is different from the test code above, which works. Here are the relevant sections of my code:
pub struct ThreadInfo {
    stop_flag: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    join_handle: JoinHandle<AI>,
}

impl ThreadInfo {
    pub fn stop(self) -> AI {
        println!("stopping");
        self.stop_flag.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
        println!("stop flag main thread: {}", self.stop_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
        let mut ai = self.join_handle.join().expect("failed to join thread");
        ai.stop_flag = None;
        println!("stopped");
        ai
    }
}


pub struct AI {
    move_data: AllMoveData,
    hashes: Hashes,
    game: Game,
    name: String,
    transposition_table: TranspositionTable,
    last_principal_variation: Vec<EncodedMove>,
    stop_flag: Option<Arc<AtomicBool>>,
    uninterupted_best_move: Option<EncodedMove>,
}
impl AI {
    pub fn start_thread(mut self) -> ThreadInfo {
        let stop_flag = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
        let stop_flag_clone = Arc::clone(&stop_flag);
        self.stop_flag = Some(stop_flag_clone);

        println!("starting");

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("thread start");
            panic!("thread started! yay!");
            for depth in 1..MAX_DEPTH {
                let start_time = Instant::now();
                let evaluation = self.negamax(&self.game.deep_clone(), depth, 0, -INFINITY, INFINITY);
                let pv_string = self.reconstruct_principal_variation();
                if self.check_stop_flag() { break; }
                let depth_duration = start_time.elapsed();
                Self::uci_print_evaluation_info(evaluation, depth, depth_duration, pv_string);
                self.uninterupted_best_move = Some(self.last_principal_variation[0]);
            }
            self
        });

        println!("started {:?}", handle);

        ThreadInfo {
            stop_flag: stop_flag,
            join_handle: handle,
        }
    }

    fn check_stop_flag(&self) -> bool {
        if let Some(stop_flag) = &self.stop_flag {
            return stop_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
        }
        false
    }
}

And here is the part of main.rs that calls this code:
                
                    let ai_thread = ai.start_thread();
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(move_time));
                    ai = ai_thread.stop();
                    writeln!(handle, "bestmove {}", ai.get_best_move()).unwrap();
                

the negamax and quiescence functions call the check_stop_flag at the start of the function and within their loops, so it just returns 0 and uses the results from the last search that finished. When I run the main function with 1000 milliseconds, it does wait a second between printing "starting" and "stopping", but it never gets to "stopped", and never prints a move. It doesn't seem to even try to run any of the code inside of the thread. What makes my code not behave the way that the simplified version does?

Without a Minimal Reproducible Example, you cannot post your question here. To create one (and maybe solve the problem by yourself in the process), remove more and more code until the problem no longer reproduce.

What printout do you actually get from your engine?

In an unrelated side-note, notice that Ordering::SeqCst is pointless here; you can use Relaxed since there is no other memory-operation to synchronize to. .join() does guarantee that all writes by the joined thread are visible to the joining thread when .join() returns.

Turns out the problem was println! Statements. They work just fine in the test function’s thread, but put a printline function in the ai thread and it freezes. My engine no longer prints info as it searches, but it does now function and it can give the info for the last search.

If this is your problem, notice that "not printing" does not solve the underlying issue, as other functions in your "ai-loop" may try to print (think panics). println!() acquires the underlying lock on std::io::Stdout, and something in your main thread may be holding that lock, blocking the ai-thread from making progress whenever it tries to acquire that lock for whatever reason. This is usually only true if you lock std::io::Stdout yourself or you have some other code that does that (e.g. logging).
